# Jetty. How to set defaultUseCaches to false without xml file

Tags: java, jetty

I'm getting the exception:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: zip file closed

The solution is found - set in jetty.xml:

```
<Set class="org.eclipse.jetty.util.resource.Resource"
     name="defaultUseCaches">false</Set>
```

Can I set this option without any xml file, in embedded way? Maybe like I'm setting init parameters: context.setInitParameter(...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at Jetty 9.2, __defaultUseCaches is a public static field of Resource and it has accessor methods, so you can simply do:

```
Resource.setDefaultUseCaches(true)
```